# Python vk_api беседа

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

У меня вопрос по поводу VK_API&Python.
Возможно ли как-то отловить эвент добавления и удаления участников в беседу (примеры на скринах)?
Бот работает через VkLongPoll. Отлавливает эвенты как группы, так и страницы. Мне необходимо проверять кто добавляет, и кого добавляют. Если участник добавляет группу, то происходит выдача варна например.

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='='*********')')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, айди_группы)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

vk_my_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='*********')
mylongpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_my_session)
myvk = vk_my_session.get_api()
```

сами пулы работают через:

```
for eventt in mylongpoll.listen():
     if eventt.type == VkEventType.********

for event in longpoll.listen():
     if event.type == VkBotEventType.********
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjh0B.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK72S.png

Comment: обратитесь к документации vk long poll https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll_3

Comment: Александр, в документации не написано. Нашёл на просторах интернета такую замечательную вещь как event.action. В ней как раз таки и происходят все действия. Можно закрывать тикет.